# Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

1. Создать DataFrame на основе набора данных Iris2.csv
2. Определит размер данных (количество строк и столбцов).
3. Вывести столбцы SepalLengthCm и Species
4. Определить среднее значение по признаку SepalLengthCm
5. Определить среднее значение по признаку SepalLengthCm сорта Iris-setosa

Ссылка на Iris2.csv
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jup5XIC3w1P8YFhUU_RC-9PFQXm8htZZ

Comment: Так не пойдет. За вас ту никто ничего делать не будет. Добавьте в вопрос Ваш код и этап на котором у Вас возникли сложности.

Comment: @Nick Proskuryakov за +реп вон что угодно сделают)

Comment: @whizz169 не поверите, но написать такую простенькую программку вообще не составляет труда. Если б попросили вручную это всё сделать тогда понятно, а в чем проблема вызвать пару методов пандас и показать человеку как с ним работать?

Comment: @Alex Zaharchuk проблема в том, что здесь не поощряется решать за других задачи, даже простые, если они не приводили свой вариант решения или хотя-бы попыток. Если бы вопрос был посложнее, его бы сразу заминусовали, возможно и вы тоже, и никто не стал бы его решать. А эти самые пару методов пандас можно и в документации посмотреть или в любой статье по пандасу на Хабре каком-нибудь они будут на первой же странице.

Comment: @AlexZaharchuk, это скорее не вопрос, а тех. задание - сделайте за меня пять пунктов. Я и сам иногда отвечаю на вопросы, в которых нет попыток решения, но я стараюсь делать это только в тех случаях, когда есть подозрение, что человек не знает как вообще подойти к проблеме или "находится в ступоре". В данном вопросе - это скорее просто лень. Получив ответы на все свои вопросы с первой попытки, в будущем автор врядли будет заморачиваться правильным оформлением вопросов,  поиском и попытками решить вопрос самому. Кроме того вопрос, состоящий из пяти пунктов врядли пригодится кому-нибудь еще)

Comment: @AlexZaharchuk, PS я ваш ответ не минусовал, но и плюсовать не буду - дабы не поощрять)

Comment: ["Как задать хороший вопрос?"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) ["Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример?"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('./my_data.csv')
countOfRows = len(df.index)
countOfColumns = len(df.columns)
print(df['SepalLengthCm'])
print(df['Species'])

print(df['SepalLengthCm'].mean())
print(df.loc[df['Species'] == 'Iris-setosa']['SepalLengthCm'].mean())
```